# display all the tables from your server using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know if its possible to display **all the tables** from the server using TSQL even if they are from different databases? How? Thanks.

**NOTE** : display all tables even if they came from different databases (but the same server)

Comment: Using these queries only returns the tables of the database where you are currently selecting.
Select * from Sys.tables where Type = 'U'

Select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use undocumented `sp_MSforeachdb` procedure to get details of all tables in same server use this

```
CREATE TABLE #table_list
  (
     TABLE_CATALOG NVARCHAR (256),
     TABLE_SCHEMA  SYSNAME,
     TABLE_NAME    SYSNAME,
     TABLE_TYPE    VARCHAR (10)
  )

EXECUTE master.sys.Sp_msforeachdb
  'USE [?];insert into #table_list select * from information_schema.tables where table_catalog not in (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'')' 

Select * from #table_list
```

Comment: Is there a way where it is treated as one query?

Comment: @JanLeeYu - check now

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me... you two with Mohamed Badr almost have the same answer. @VR46

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #TableNames ( Name NVARCHAR(MAX) );

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT  name
    FROM    sys.databases
    WHERE   name NOT IN ( 'master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb' );
OPEN db_cursor; 
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor  INTO @DatabaseName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE('USE ' + @DatabaseName + ';INSERT  INTO #TableNames( Name )( SELECT name FROM sys.tables );'); 
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor  INTO @DatabaseName;
    END;
CLOSE db_cursor; 
DEALLOCATE db_cursor; 

SELECT  *
FROM    #TableNames;

DROP TABLE #TableNames;
```

This query first selects all databases names at your server then use cursor to loop the result and select table names into temp table `#TableNames` and select the final result from it

Comment: Is there a way to just return all the data into only one result set?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me... you two with VR46 almost have the same answer. @Mohamed Badr

Comment: I'll just accept  VR46's answer for now because Ii seems clearer for me but you really did a great job and thanks for that. :)